# xmlbeans: deep equals not implemented

Tags: apache-poi, xmlbeans, apache-poi-4

I'm trying to use `org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFNumbering.getIdOfAbstractNum(XWPFAbstractNum abstractNum)` to test if the given abstractNum exists or not. This call ends up in:

```
CTAbstractNumImpl(XmlComplexContentImpl).equal_to(XmlObject) line: 79   
CTAbstractNumImpl(XmlObjectBase).valueEqualsImpl(XmlObject) line: 2393  
CTAbstractNumImpl(XmlObjectBase).valueEquals(XmlObject) line: 2434  
XWPFNumbering.getIdOfAbstractNum(XWPFAbstractNum) line: 222 
...
```

Unfortunately, `org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlComplexContentImpl.equal_to(XmlObject)` isn't implemented properly and returns always true:

```
public boolean equal_to(XmlObject complexObject)
{
    if (!_schemaType.equals(complexObject.schemaType()))
        return false;

    // BUGBUG: by-value structure comparison undone
    return true;
}
```

Is there an alternative to deeply compare such xml objects, or to find out if the abstract numbering exists?

Answer (score 1):

Luckily there was an old post over here, which has a solution attached: [http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xml-xmlbeans-user/200310.mbox/%3cOF7B942026.9900E6EE-ONCA256DC8.00064356@tmca.com.au%3e](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xml-xmlbeans-user/200310.mbox/%3COF7B942026.9900E6EE-ONCA256DC8.00064356@tmca.com.au%3E)

This is slightly modified content, which allows to compare two xml objects by calling the method `lenientlyCompareTwoXmlStrings(XmlObject, XmlObject)`:

```
package bookmarks;


import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.common.QNameHelper;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.common.XmlWhitespace;

/**
* This originates from an author called Dmitri.Coleba, see attached source here:
* http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xml-xmlbeans-user/200310.mbox/%3cOF7B942026.9900E6EE-ONCA256DC8.00064356@tmca.com.au%3e
* 
* <p>
* Deep comparison of two xml objects.
* 
* @author Markus Pscheidt
*
*/
public class XBeanCompare {

    public static class Diagnostic {
        private StringBuffer message = new StringBuffer();

        void add(String s) {
            message.append(s).append("\n");
        }

        public String toString() {
            return message.toString();
        }
    }

    /**
    * Provides a utility to compare the xml inside the two strings.
    * 
    * @return true if the xml inside the two strings is the same
    */
    public static boolean lenientlyCompareTwoXmlStrings(XmlObject actualObj, XmlObject expectObj, Diagnostic diag) {
        boolean match = true;

        XmlCursor cur1 = actualObj.newCursor();
        XmlCursor cur2 = expectObj.newCursor();

        cur1.toFirstChild();
        cur2.toFirstChild();

        while (cur1.currentTokenType() != XmlCursor.TokenType.STARTDOC) {
            if (!compareNamesAndAttributes(cur1, cur2, diag)) {
                match = false;
            }

            boolean hasChildren1 = cur1.toFirstChild();
            boolean hasChildren2 = cur2.toFirstChild();
            if (hasChildren1 != hasChildren2) {
                diag.add("Topology differs: one document has " + "children where the other does not ("
                        + QNameHelper.pretty(cur1.getName()) + ", " + QNameHelper.pretty(cur2.getName()) + ")."); // TODO:
                                                                                                                    // where?
                match = false;
                if (hasChildren1) {
                    cur1.toParent();
                    hasChildren1 = false;
                }
                if (hasChildren2) {
                    cur2.toParent();
                    hasChildren2 = false;
                }
            } else if (hasChildren1 == false) {
                if (!wsCollapseEqual(cur1.getTextValue(), cur2.getTextValue())) {
                    diag.add("Value '" + cur1.getTextValue() + "' differs from value '" + cur2.getTextValue() + "'.");
                    match = false;
                }
            }

            if (hasChildren1)
                continue;

            for (;;) {
                boolean hasSibling1 = cur1.toNextSibling();
                boolean hasSibling2 = cur2.toNextSibling();

                if (hasSibling1 != hasSibling2) {
                    diag.add("Topology differs: one document has " + "siblings where the other does not."); // TODO:
                                                                                                            // where?
                    hasSibling1 = false;
                    hasSibling2 = false;
                }

                if (hasSibling1)
                    break;

                cur1.toParent();
                cur2.toParent();

                if (cur1.currentTokenType() == XmlCursor.TokenType.STARTDOC)
                    break;
            }
        }
        return match;
    }

    private static boolean compareNamesAndAttributes(XmlCursor cur1, XmlCursor cur2, Diagnostic diag) {
        if (!cur1.getName().equals(cur2.getName())) {
            diag.add("Element names '" + QNameHelper.pretty(cur1.getName()) + "' and '"
                    + QNameHelper.pretty(cur2.getName()) + "' do not match.");
            return false;
        }

        String elemName = QNameHelper.pretty(cur1.getName());

        boolean more = cur1.toFirstAttribute();
        if (more) {
            for (; more; more = cur1.toNextAttribute()) {
                String text1 = cur1.getTextValue();
                String text2 = cur2.getAttributeText(cur1.getName());
                if (text2 == null) {
                    diag.add("Attribute '" + QNameHelper.pretty(cur1.getName()) + "' " + " of element '" + elemName
                            + "' not present.");
                    return false;
                }

                if (!wsCollapseEqual(text1, text2)) {
                    diag.add("Attribute values for '" + QNameHelper.pretty(cur1.getName()) + "' " + " of element '"
                            + elemName + "' don't match.");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            cur1.toParent();
        }

        more = cur2.toFirstAttribute();
        if (more) {
            for (; more; more = cur2.toNextAttribute()) {
                String text1 = cur1.getAttributeText(cur2.getName());
                if (text1 == null) {
                    diag.add("Attribute '" + QNameHelper.pretty(cur2.getName()) + "' " + " of element '" + elemName
                            + "' not present.");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            cur2.toParent();
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static boolean wsCollapseEqual(String s1, String s2) {
        String s1c = XmlWhitespace.collapse(s1);
        String s2c = XmlWhitespace.collapse(s2);
        return (s1c.equals(s2c));
    }

}
```